# Skype Starts with the Console

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, skype

I use Linux Mind Debian Edition 2 'Betsy.' I used the [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/skype#Debian_8_.22Jessie.22) to install skype.

Now, skype opens whenever I open the terminal. Skype closes upon closing the console. The console is useless until I open a second instance of it, while the useless one is still running.

Why could this be this? How can I prevent it?

**EDIT:**

Thanks, AFH, Bash starts skype. I edited the output of the output of the command from below in order to avoid posting more than two links. (I may not post links until I have at least ten reputation points.)

```
george@pc ~ $ grep skype ~/.bash* ~/.profile /etc/bash* /etc/profile
/home/george/.bash_history:gdebi skype-install.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:gdebi skype-install.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:gdebi skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:gdebi /Downloads/skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:gdebi Downloads/skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo wget -O skype-install.deb skype.com /go/getskype-linux-deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo gdebi skype-install.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo gdebi skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo gdebi skype-install.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo dpkg -i skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo dpkg -i skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo dpkg -i skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo dpkg -i skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin:i386 skype:i386
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo gdebi skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:skype
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo skype
/home/george/.bash_history:echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ /usr/bin/skype" >> ~/.bashrc
/home/george/.bash_history:skype
/home/george/.bash_history:skype
/home/george/.bash_history:skype
/home/george/.bash_history:skype.exe
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo dpkg -i skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:wget thhp:download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubunto- precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:wget download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubunto- precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo wget download.skype.com/linux/skype- ubunto-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo gdebi skype-dbian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo gdebi skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
/home/george/.bash_history:wget -O skype-install.deb www.skype.com /go/getskype-linux-deb
/home/george/.bash_history:sudo dpkg -i skype-install.deb
/home/george/.bashrc:LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ /usr/bin/skype
grep: /etc/bash_completion.d: Is a directory
```

Comment: Check what has launched Skype: `gnome-system-monitor` in tree view is the easiest way to do this, or you can do `ps -efl|less` and find `skype` and then its parent program. If it's `bash`, then you need to check for references to `skype` in the initialisation files: `grep skype ~/.bash* ~/.profile /etc/bash* /etc/profile` (assuming Mint and Ububtu use the same files, both being Debian-based). If it's something else, then I'll need to know what it is before I can advise further.

Comment: It is bash, @AFH.

Comment: OK, so did the `grep` find anything?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what it found, @AFH. You can see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the `.bash_history` entries: they are commands that you have typed previously and will not be invoked again except from the command line.

In fact the problem is in the line:

```
/home/george/.bashrc:LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ /usr/bin/skype
```

This command sets the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then runs `/usr/bin/skype`, which is what you are observing.

Assuming `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` is the correct environment variable value, it certainly should not be followed by the `skype` invocation, so remove the space and what follows.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm sorry, but I don't know how to remove the said line. I'm rather new to linux.

Comment: Just edit the file `/home/george/.bashrc` with any text editor, such as `gedit`.